# Array of objects in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to have such a `array of objects` in terraform:

```
param ArrayOfRules array = [
  {
    name: '1stRule'
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'

  }
  {
    name: '2ndRule'
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.1'
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.1'
  }
]
```

On which i would like to simply iterare in order to create firewall rules.

```
resource sqlServerFirewallRules 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules@2022-02-01-preview' = [for rule in ArrayOfRules: {
  parent: serverName_resource
  name: rule.name
  properties: {
    startIpAddress: rule.startIpAddress
    endIpAddress: rule.endIpAddress
  }

}]
```

I know that i could to something like this in `bicep` but I don't know how to do it in terraform.

Comment: Is there a resource in Azure that you would use to create what you need?

Comment: @MarkoE `resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule"`

Answer (score 2):

- You need to create variable like

```
variable "ArrayOfRules" {
 type = list(map(string))
}
```

- You need to assign variable value like this

```
var.ArrayOfRules = [
  {
    name: '1stRule'
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'

  },
  {
    name: '2ndRule'
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.1'
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.1'
  }
]
```

- You need to call dynamic block in your resource..

```
resource sqlServerFirewallRules 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules@2022-02-01-preview' {
  parent: serverName_resource
  name: rule.name
    dynamic "eachElementinArray" {
    for_each = each.value.eachElementinArray

    properties {
      name     = name.value.type
      startIpAddress = eachElementinArray.value.startIpAddress
      endIpAddress   = eachElementinArray.value.endIpAddress
    }
  }

}
```

You may have to change some syntax... but on a high level, your terraform will look like the above..

Comment: after a `terraform apply` it asks me for: 
`var.ArrayOfRules Enter a value:`
What should i put in here

Comment: I have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545843/array-of-objects-in-terraform/73546043?noredirect=1#comment129875662_73546043:~:text=%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%271stRule%27%0A%20%20%20%20startIpAddress%3A%20%270.0.0.0%27%0A%20%20%20%20endIpAddress%3A%20%270.0.0.0%27%0A%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%272ndRule%27%0A%20%20%20%20startIpAddress%3A%20%270.0.0.1%27%0A%20%20%20%20endIpAddress%3A%20%270.0.0.1%27%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D)